# How can I select the longest string when using GROUP BY for multiple columns in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, group-by

I have below tables with duplicates values. i want to take only max length text from it.

```
+----+---------------------------------+-------------------+
| ID | Text                            | no                |
+----+---------------------------------+-------------------+
| 1  | lorem ipsum ipsum               | 8955\5445         |
+----+---------------------------------+-------------------+
| 1  | ipsum                           | 1879668\4554\4554 |
+----+---------------------------------+-------------------+
| 1  | lorem ipsum ipsum               | 5464              |
+----+---------------------------------+-------------------+
| 2  | lorem ipsum ipsum derome        | 13465465\54555\45 |
+----+---------------------------------+-------------------+
| 2  | lorem ipsum derome ipsum derome | 555454            |
+----+---------------------------------+-------------------+
```

My Query:

```
select id,MAX(text),MAX(no) from table1 group by id
```

Result:

```
    +----+--------------------------+-----------+
| id | Text                     | no        |
+----+--------------------------+-----------+
| 1  | lorem ipsum ipsum        | 8955\5445 |
+----+--------------------------+-----------+
| 2  | lorem ipsum ipsum derome | 555454    |
+----+--------------------------+-----------+
```

Expected Output:

```
   +----+--------------------------+-------------------+
| id | Text                     | no                |
+----+--------------------------+-------------------+
| 1  | lorem ipsum ipsum        | 1879668\4554\4554 |
+----+--------------------------+-------------------+
| 2  | lorem ipsum ipsum derome | 13465465\54555\45 |
+----+--------------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: For each id you want longest text and maximum no, unrelated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to want both the longest text and the highest number looking at your expected results.

Let's make some test data;

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TestData
GO
CREATE TABLE #TestData (ID int, Text varchar(50), no int)
INSERT INTO #TestData (ID, Text, no)
VALUES
(1,'lorem ipsum ipsum',8955)
,(1,'ipsum',6879668)
,(1,'lorem ipsum ipsum',5464)
,(2,'lorem ipsum ipsum derome',63465465)
,(2,'lorem ipsum derome ipsum derome',555454)
```

I've done this as subqueries to get both max values separately. The first inner join is just for filtering, the second one returns the highest value from the `no` column.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
t.id
,m.Text Text
,MAX(t.no) Number
FROM #TestData t
LEFT JOIN  --Get the max data length
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
        t.ID
        ,t.Text
        FROM #TestData t
        JOIN 
            (
                SELECT 
                ID
                ,MAX(len(Text)) MaxLen
                FROM #TestData 
                GROUP BY ID
            ) mx 
        ON t.ID = mx.ID
        AND LEN(t.Text) = mx.MaxLen
    ) m 
ON t.ID = m.ID
LEFT JOIN --Get the max no
        (
        SELECT 
        ID
        ,MAX(LEN(no)) MaxNo
        FROM #TestData 
        GROUP BY ID
    ) n
ON t.ID = n.ID
AND LEN(t.no) = n.MaxNo
GROUP BY t.id, m.Text
```

The results come out as;

```
id  Text                            MaxNo
1   lorem ipsum ipsum               6879668
2   lorem ipsum derome ipsum derome 63465465
```

Comment: i want max length number too not max of number

Comment: That's going to be the same thing. The max number is going to be the longest by definition.

Comment: in my case i declare number as varchar its giving different output

Comment: I've just updated my answer, give that one a go now. It's looking at max length of no rather than max of no. I've also done a bit more aggregation as you may well have two numbers that are the same length. If this happens then it will take the highest value)

Comment: it searching for longest text and number in single row if one of the condition get false it will not give you any result.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I've just updated my answer and it works as expected, let me know if this resolves it for you or if you need further clarification.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it by combining a RANK function with a CTE. Someting like this:

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT 
  id
  ,text
  ,no
  ,RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY LEN(text) DESC) AS pos
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE pos = 1
```

Comment: That's not going to take into account that he also wants the max 'no' by the looks of it which does not match the longest text field.

Answer (score 2):

Try this query, this return what do you need.
It works

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.Text,
       a.no
FROM table AS a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id,
           MAX(LEN(Text)) AS lenght
    FROM table
    GROUP BY id
) b
     ON LEN(a.Text) = b.lenght
        AND a.id = b.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to do a `NOT EXISTS`, i.e. return a row as long as no other row with same id has a longer text. Self `JOIN` with a `GROUP BY` that returns each id's maximum no.

```
select t1.id, t1.Text, t3.no
from tablename t1
    join (select id, max(no) no from tablename group by id) t3 on t1.id = t3.id
where not exists (select * from tablename t2 
                  where t2.id = t1.id
                    and length(t2.Text) > length(t1.Text))
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, can be achieved by following query if we want to retrieve just the max length `Text`

```
Select top 1 id,Test,no  --Top n, depending upon requirement
From
(Select id, Test, no, LEN(TEST) as Length
From #TableName)B
Order by Length Desc;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT Id,Text,Number
WHERE LENGTH(description) = (
           SELECT MAX(LENGTH(Text))
GROUP BY ID,Text,Number
```